# Box inside the Box in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-styles

I am trying to put a box inside another box.

Here is my code:

```
    \begin{figure}
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \tikz \draw[fill=green!5] (0,0) rectangle (8,8)   node at (2.5,0.9){Experimental data = $A$};
         \tikz \draw[fill=pink] (0,0) rectangle (7,7)   node at (.5,0.5){$B$};
   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

I tried different coordinates, but I could not manage to put "box B" it inside the "box A". What am I missing? Any advice,help?

Comment: Simply remove `\tikz` before the `\draw` commands. `\tikz` is for drawing outside of the `tikzpicture`environment.  Remark: the text "Experimental data = $A$" will be hide by the pink square behind it.

Comment: thank you,it solved my problem !!!!